# How to reference specific characters in data frame column

Tags: sql, r

In SQL I can reference part of a character in a character vector using `"%lname"` where the `%` could be any characters that come before the `lname` part of any of the observations. I need to accomplish the same thing in r but cannot figure out how. I realize there is probably an easy answer online and probably on this site but I cannot think of the term for this and had a difficult time wording it to find an answer. Thanks for any help

*EDIT*: 
So SQL code like this that references any observation which the name begins with J

`customer_T.cust_name LIKE 'J%'`

how would I do something similar in r to accomplish

`ifelse(train$VAR1 %in% '%XX', 1, 0)`

where there could be any characters that come before XX

Comment: Use ```grepl()``` function or ```str_detect()```.

Comment: `ifelse(grepl(pattern = "XX$", x = train$VAR1), 1, 0)` will give flag rows ending in XX. You should probably find a nice little regex tutorial to understand what's going on. (`$` indicates the end of the string.)